# Add more multiple select fields with name+x

Tags: javascript, forms, loops

In javascript i have the following function

```
function addMore(){
    var html = $('.wrapper').html();
    $(".insert-after").after(html);
}
```

In html i have the following code

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <select name="s_allergies[][]" multiple required>
        <option value="none">None</option>
        <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
        <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
        <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
        <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
        <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
        <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
        <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

in my app i have an "Add More" button that will copy and paste the fields.
In order for me to process them through php i need a way to increment the name of the select field to be "s_allergies[1][] .... s_allergies[2][]" etc.. however, i can't seem to get it to work using

i'm not a pro at javascript, can someone guide me a bit?

thanks

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/baqNKx

Comment: wooh wooh, you asked how to add more "options" to your select using JS and i wrote two examples @user1986245 , what you are trying to achieve in your codepen won't work, the indexes are defined automatically once you send the request to your server

Comment: in simple terms, what i need to do is change the name attr to the new added field. For example, the template is `name=s_allergies[][]`, when i click add i need the next one to be `name=s_allergies[1][]` and then the next one `s_allergies[2][]` and so on...

Comment: aaaaaah, you want to copy the whole options set so the user can see the same options again?

Comment: i have a event registration page, the user has the ability to add more people. the additional people will have the same set of questions.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to define an ID to your select in case you'll have more than one, then this is what you need to do in plain JS

```js
function addMore(){
  child=document.createElement('option');
  child.text='Some Text';
  child.val='some Value';
  document.getElementById('selector').appendChild(child);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <select id="selector" name="s_allergies[][]" multiple required>
        <option value="none">None</option>
        <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
        <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
        <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
        <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
        <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
        <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
        <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick=addMore()>Click</button>
</div>
```

And this using jQuery:

```js
function addMore(){
  $('#selector').append($('<option value="someValue">Some Text</option>'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <select id="selector" name="s_allergies[][]" multiple required>
        <option value="none">None</option>
        <option value="Gluten">Gluten Allergy</option>
        <option value="Nut">Nut Allergy</option>
        <option value="Shellfish">Shellfish Allergy</option>
        <option value="Lactose">Lactose Allergy</option>
        <option value="Egg">Egg Allergy</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian</option>
        <option value="Vegetarian with Seafood">Vegetarian/Seafood</option>
        <option value="No Pork">No Pork</option>
        <option value="No Red Meat">No Red Meat</option>
    </select>
    <button onClick=addMore()>Click</button>
</div>
```